# Modification to a code to run not only in PHP 5.3

Tags: php

Hello this is the cod I am using but as the author said it runs on PHP 5.3
I am using 5.2.17 I guess this is why I have this error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION` on line 14 (`usort($entries, function ($x, $y) {`)

What can I do about it ?

```
$feeds = array(
    'http://www.example.org/feed1.rss',
    'http://www.example.org/feed2.rss'
);

// Get all feed entries
$entries = array();
foreach ($feeds as $feed) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($feed);
    $entries = array_merge($entries, $xml->xpath('/rss//item'));
}

// Sort feed entries by pubDate (ascending)
usort($entries, function ($x, $y) {
    return strtotime($x->pubDate) - strtotime($y->pubDate);
});

print_r($entries);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because that code is using a lamba function.

To accomplish this in pre 5.3, you could simply define the function and pass the function name as the argument, i.e.,

```
function mySort($x, $y) {
    return strtotime($x->pubDate) - strtotime($y->pubDate);
}

usort($entries, 'mySort');
```

or create the function using create_function()

Comment: Hi there thanks for your answer i works! But do you have any idea why the sorting doesnt work ?

Answer (score 2):

PHP 5.2.x does not support anonymous functions. You can still use `usort()` but you will need to give a function to sort:

```
usort($entries, "mySort" );

function mySort($x, $y) {
    return strtotime($x->pubDate) - strtotime($y->pubDate);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace

```
usort($entries, function ($x, $y) {
    return strtotime($x->pubDate) - strtotime($y->pubDate);
});
```

by

```
usort(
    $entries, 
    create_function(
        '$x, $y', 
        'return strtotime($x->pubDate) - strtotime($y->pubDate);'
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Sort feed entries by pubDate (ascending)

function mysort($x, $y) {
    return strtotime($x->pubDate) - strtotime($y->pubDate);
}

usort($entries, "mysort");
```

PHP 5.3+ allows the use of anonymous(lambda) functions. These are like normal functions, but instead of a name, you get a reference in a variable, example:

```
$myf = function() {} ;
```

Older PHP versions do not have this feature, so you have to use a global (normal) function:

```
function myf (){
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like your function inside of `usort()` is confusing PHP. Try this:

```
// Sort feed entries by pubDate (ascending)
function timeFix ($x, $y) {
  return strtotime($x->pubDate) - strtotime($y->pubDate);
})

$timeFix = timeFix($x, $y);

usort($entries, $timeFix);
```

Or better yet

```
usort($entries, timeFix($x, $y));
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: The function is a callback to uSort, and is not supposed to be called directly.